# difference between lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp lmtp:unix:public/dovecot-lmtp

Tags: postfix, dovecot

What is the difference between:

`lmtp:unix:public/dovecot-lmtp` and `lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp`

in postfix?

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted.  This is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 4):

It basically refers to the url at which the unix socket will be found.
`lmtp:unix:public/dovecot-lmtp` corresponds to `/var/spool/postfix/public/dovecot-lmtp` while `lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp` is `/var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp`.

The semantic between those two folders is rougly that access permission (in term of unix's user/group) is more lenient for public than for private. It might depend on your distribution, but on mine, you can enter public with only a `postdrop` membership while private is restricted to `postfix` uid.

Obviously, you still need dovecot and postfix's configurations to use the same folder.

Comment: More importantly, if you have something like spamassassin in the delivery loop (which runs under a non-postfix user) lmtp will need to be using `public`, or else you'll get timeouts because spamd can't enter `private`.  smfh that was like 2 days of my life!